# Writing JSON File Containing Array Continuously

Tags: python, json

I want to create a JSON file with Python. JSON structure looks like :

```
{
    "index_pattern" : "all_packets"
    "packets" : [
        {
            "packet_type" : "TCP"
            "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
            "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
        },
        {
            "packet_type" : "ICMP"
            "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
            "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever I catch a packet with wireshark module, I want to add that packet to say myoutput.json file. The problem is, using something like

```
f = open("myoutput.json", "a")
f.write({
            "packet_type" : "ICMP"
            "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
            "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
        })
```

is not suitable, because I do not have a graceful shutdown and I can not add necessary  closing paranthesis to finish up the JSON. So I need to write in BETWEEN the packet array. What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Could you store this in a NoSQL db instead, and just send the packets to that?

Comment: Hi, thank you for attention. My project requirement is creating a JSON file as an output that another program (say X) can read. And program X already uses ElasticSearch so we may not involve another storing tool into project. That's why I we can't guess.@doctorlove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you writing the file:

```
import json
with open('myoutput.json', 'a') as fo:
    json.dump({
        "packet_type" : "ICMP",
        "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
        "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
          }, fo)
```

When reading the file, do:

```
with open('myoutput.json') as fo:
    data = fo.read()
    data = data.replace('}{', '},{')
    data = '[' + data + ']'
    data = json.loads(data)
    result = {"index_pattern" : "all_packets",
              "packets": data}
```

#### Edit

You can also create a helper class to do it:

```
import json

class WriteObject:
    def __init__(self, fname='myoutput.json'):
        self.fname = fname

    def push(self, data):
        #    data_example={
        #    "packet_type" : "ICMP",
        #    "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
        #    "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
        #    }
        with open(self.fname, 'a') as fo:
            json.dump(data, fo)
    def get_all(self):
        with open(self.fname) as fo:
            data = fo.read()
            data = data.replace('}{', '},{')
            data = '[' + data + ']'
            data = json.loads(data)
            result = {"index_pattern" : "all_packets",
                      "packets": data}
        return result

# usage
obj = WriteObject()

obj.push({
        "packet_type" : "ICMP",
        "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
        "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
          })
```

Comment: But did you actually check if your code is working?

Comment: @taras, Yes, in Jupyter!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. To be more clear, I want make a push operation in packets field that lies in a file. Just to demonstrate its like, 
myoutput.json["packets"].push({
        "packet_type" : "ICMP",
        "source_ip" : "192.168.0.2",
        "destination_ip" : "192.168.0.114"
          })

Comment: Solution with the class implementation solved it. Thanks to all of you <3

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is `json.load`ing the entire file into python object, say `data` and appending the `packet` to `data["packets"]`. Then you need to write the updated `data` back to your json file.
The drawback of this approach is the need to constantly read and write data to json file.

It can be improved by aggregating a list of packets (so you temporary save your packets to `packets` list) and updating the json file only when it reaches some predefined size (say, when `len(packets) == 20`). After that you can empty `packets` and start gathering data into it again.